# C# and something like SharedPreferences

Tags: c#

I was thinking about something like SharedPreferences from android in c#. I mean I want to save value one variable even if I close application and run again. I want to save this value every time when I close application and run again. How I can do that? I know that is possible when I am using data base but maybe is any other solution?

Comment: Did you try with application settings???

Comment: No, because I am new in c#. Could you tell me more or give me any link?

Comment: Start from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a65txexh.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C# you can use User or Application Settings. The user settings are different per user while with the application settings you can set one value for all users. To set initial Values you have an editor or you can write XML directly:

```
<setting name="HelloText" serializeAs="String">
   <value>This is the setting value</value>
</setting>
```

To get the value in your code you can write this:

```
this.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.HelloText;
```

On this [MSDN-Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) you find all you need to start with Settings in C#.

Comment: How to save the user setting when the value stored is changed?

Answer (score 0):

it depneds on the architecture of your application,

you may have embedded databases like SQL Server CE,

you may use the file system (having your own configuration file)

you may use the registry editor,

you may use the cloud to store user values globally,

there are a lot of options depending on your needs and your criteria

Answer (score 0):

[IsolatedStorage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or WindowsStorage (in case of Windows Store Apps) are kind of alternative to SharedPreferences in C#.

An excerpt from article [Windows Phone: Storing Data and Preferences](http://windowsphone.interoperabilitybridges.com/articles/android-to-wp7-chapter-6-storing-data-and-preferences)

> Android provides SharedPreferences class to save and retrieve
>   persistent key-value pairs of primitive data types. This data survives
>   across application sessions. Similarly, Windows Phone provides the
>   IsolatedStorageSettings class to persist key-value pairs. Windows
>   IsolatedStorageSettings are stored in the application specific
>   IsolatedStorage.